# Does Martin Ledge uncover?

Tags: ocean, mapping

In the [current Wikipedia article for Martin Ledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Ledge) it reads: "Martin Ledge is small barren rocks that barely stick out of the waters". However, the NOAA chart for the area shows a low tide depth of 16 feet, which indicates that the rocks do not uncover. Which is right, the wikipedia article or the chart?

[image]

Comment: NOAA should be right, as the numbers on a nautical chart are water depths at Mean Lower Low Water. Also, it just doesn't look like it: http://www.bostonharborbeacon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Martin_Ledge.jpg What is the date of the chart?

Comment: @arkaia The rocks in that picture are Little Brewster Island and Boston Light.

Comment: This is the article of the photo: http://www.bostonharborbeacon.com/2012/07/07/striped-bass-fishing-success-using-live-bait/

Comment: @arkaia and Tyler Just so it's stated explicitly, the chart and the photo both show the red nun (conical buoy) number 4 near Martin Ledge.